# Good ideas for a file directory for an application made with VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program that should be able to launch a game. And so what i'm looking for to create is a folder, in which my application, the game and all the other files should be placed.

Currently all the files are on my computer, but i would like for the program to be universal to any PC, so that when running the setup, i get to choose where all my files will be placed (create Root Directory where i unzip the application). So if i place the program in a folder, all my files would be placed in that same folder.

Feel free to ask me about this, as i might be a little confusing.

-nikko4913

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Programs belong in c:\program files.  It is universal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the windows variable %programfiles%